# why are 'required variables' declared outside module.exports

Tags: node.js

I understand that functionality is scoped inside module.exports. But I always see variables declared outside. So shouldn't it be inside ?

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: because the variable scope to be on whole body.

Comment: No. The required values aren't visible outside the file, so there's no reason to. Also, `modules.exports` can be used in a variety of ways, some of which wouldn't make the requirements terribly obvious. Conventionally they're required at the top, as you've shown.

Comment: How about the memory allocation? How are these 'private' variables being freed regarding the module life cycle?

Answer (score 3):

The code outside of the module.exports is not visible outside of the file. Typically includes libraries and functions used within the code you are writing.  I guess you could think of this as being "private" functions / variables.

I don't know if you are writing code inside of module.exports but I prefer not to.  I find this to be more readable:

```
var doSomethingImpl = function(){
}

module.exports = {
   doSomething: doSomethingImpl
}
```

or

```
var doSomethingImpl = function(){
}

module.exports.doSomething = doSomethingImpl
```

or even

```
module.exports.doSomething = function(){
}
```